# Problema al importar Swagger en Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework, swagger

tengo una inquietud, estoy tratando de documentar mi APIREST con Swagger, la API la hice en Django rest framework.

Mi proyecto lo tengo desde un ambiente virtual con `pipenv`,
al momento de importar Swagger de la siguiente forma:

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
```

me sale este error:

```
Import "rest_framework_swagger.views" could not be resolved Pylancere (portMissingImports)
```

La dependencia ya la tengo instalada

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #dependencies
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'rest_framework_swagger' -> aqui,

    #myapps
    'api',

]
```

No entiendo cuál es el error al tratar de importar dicha dependencia, ya que está instalada dentro de las dependencias de mi entorno virtual, ¿Saben como solucionar este problema?